# Ubuntu 64 bit m/c , codeblocks 10.05 , function return value is changed

Tags: codeblocks

I am facing a very typical issue.
I have a function (create_instance), that returns void * .
Inside create_instance, I do a malloc for a structure, set default values to members of structure, and returns the malloced memory.

Inside create_instance, the malloc memory was 0x7fffff000080.
In the calling function, the return value of the function shows as 0xffffffffff000080.

Next the program is crashing when I try to access any member of structure which is obvious.

My question is why the value is changed when function returns.

I am using Ubutu 12.04 LTS, codeblocks 10.05 environment for my development.

Do I need to give any compiler/linker options. I tried with option -m64, but no luck.

If anybody knows about this, kindly reply back.

Kamal
Net Cloud Systems
Bangalore

Comment: I believe you omitting some important specifics. Please provide SSCCE. If problem isn't persists in SSCCE - it's a bug in your code.

Comment: This issue was resolved after making sure function signature specified in header file. In 32 bit Ubuntu environment we did not face this issue (even if some function signatures were missing from header file), however in 64 bit Ubuntu environment it is required to specify all required function signatures in header file.